# Internet Radio Streaming API

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-radio

I was thinking of using FLowPlayer, but I need to add category so then when it hits a category then a radio channel the API plays that internet radio station on the API.

Know any good api with this capability?

I was going to use ShoutCast but its not releasing anymore dev. keys.

So, any other API?

Any programming languages of html/php/css/js or any close ot that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an API which lets you control audio, then you should have a look at [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

Comment: I am looking for one to stream .pls

Comment: That's possible with SoundManager 2 but you have tweak the stream url a bit and add `;stream.nsv&type=mp3` at the end. So i.e. the stream url is `http://server:port/`, then the modified url would be this: `http://server:port/;stream.nsv&type=mp3`