# Which Internet Radio API should be used for Android app

Tags: android, api, streaming

Hi, I want to create an Android app which will broadcast radio stations.I searched on google and found mainly two APIs.

1.streamfinder.com API (showing it has 10000 radio station data and stream)

2.ShoutCast API (showing more than 40000 radio stations around the world)

But I read a query that ShoutCast stops giving development key for its API:

[Internet Radio Streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658703/internet-radio-streaming-api).
Can any one please suggest, which API should be used for internet radio streaming.